# Accessible, mobile-friendly lightbox?

Tags: jquery-plugins, mobile, lightbox, wai-aria

Is there any lightbox solution (along the lines of Fancybox, etc.) that is both accessible (VoiceOver & JAWS, etc., compatible, with perhaps WAI-ARIA roles) and mobile-friendly?

Bonus points for being a jQuery plugin.

Comment: This closed question seems to have more useful answers to this question, including photoswipe which appears to actually solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943589/open-truly-responsive-mobile-friendly-lightbox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might be too late for you but I'll answer for people who may land here from Google search: recently I used [NETEYE Touch-Gallery](https://github.com/neteye/jquery-plugins/tree/master/touch-gallery) and it worked pretty well, at least on iPhone and Android.

Comment: just checked this out, but their demo doesn't work on my Samsung Fascinate (galaxy s)

Comment: Yes, on Android Gingerbread (2.3) it shows black screen when clicking on the picture.

Comment: Demo doesn't work in iPhone 5, iOS 6.0.2; same thing - black screen.

Comment: Demo doesn't work on Samsung Galaxy S3 either. Black screen with scroll bars.

Comment: Totally broken on Android but seems to be a step in the right direction.

Comment: These forks appear to improve it, have not tested them: https://github.com/drewjw81/jquery-plugins/tree/master/touch-gallery https://github.com/pfrischmuth/jquery-plugins/tree/master/touch-gallery

Answer (score 0):

I am making the same research at the moment to integrate into our project! I have looked at a lot of them and so far my favorite in terms of quality is:
**Swipe box** 
http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/#features

I know the question is very old but I am only answering for future references as other conversation was closed as duplicate.