# Open, truly responsive, mobile-friendly lightbox

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, lightbox

I'm looking for suggestions for a [lightbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_%28JavaScript%29) plugin that is [responsive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) and mobile-friendly.

### Update

The  following are great for `dialogs` and `pop-up windows` but don't have built-in `Next`/`Previous` navigation for rotating through a list of images or videos:

- [Foundation 3](http://foundation.zurb.com/) has [Reveal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/reveal.php).
- [JQuery Mobile 1.2.0](http://jquerymobile.com/) has [Popup](http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/docs/pages/popup/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous answer was specifically looking for a light box plugin.

If you want a light box effect for galleries on mobile, consider this: http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html

Answer (score 1):

jQuery mobile has all sorts of pop-up events
http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Comment: I'm hoping for something with a little more functionality, like "Next" and "Previous" navigation for multiple images or videos, etc.